# Eclipse shorcuts (F3/ctrl+click) not working for navigation

Tags: 12.04, eclipse

Shortcut to access the declaration with the help of this shortcut is not working
Installed version of Ubuntu is 12.04
and for Eclipse it is:
Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this version of Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 but it works for me.You may assign "F3" to another action, for check it go to System Settings select Keyboard and then goto shortcuts tab, find there for "F3" shortcut, If you find it change it to another keyboard shortcut.
You should also check your eclipse because it work completely for me.

Comment: i looked up in the keyboard shortcuts sections.. but there was not shorcut listed for F3. 
Moreover, The icon for eclipse is also not appearing in my launcher, instead a ? icon is appearing

Comment: neither the other shorcut i.e. ctrl_click works for me :/

Comment: If there was not any shortcut for eclipse, i think your eclipse has problem. If you want your eclipse appear in your launcher and search result you have to install "Main Menu" (alacarte) program from software center and add tour eclipse as an item in its categories.

Comment: it was earlier not appearing in launcher and search results, but now it is appearing

Comment: i have tried everything, but that F3 simply doesn't work at all

Comment: Did you install eclipse from software center or from zip file (download from eclipse site) ?

Comment: i downloaded it from the eclipse site..

Comment: Which vendor and version of JDK did you installed? (Oracle JDK or OpenJDK)

Comment: i installed oracle one

Comment: Your configurations are like mine but i do not have any problem. Do you use JDK 7 or 6 ?

Comment: how to check that.. i tried jdk -version but that is not supported command

Comment: Did you set your JDK/bin path in your environment variable? if not you can use this link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Comment: it is giving a new error:- It says:- The Resource is not on the include path of a JavaScript project.. Please help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

These shotcuts works well with this version installed.
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junor